# Telic /atelic verb phrases

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions, tense, adverbial-phrases

What is the best way to identify the verb phrase as telic/atelic apart from adding durational adverbials(such as in-adverbial and for-adverbial) and using such lexical verbs as stop/finish?

Comment: [**Telic** verbs](https://aaas.confex.com/aaas/2017/webprogram/Paper19776.html#:~:text=EFFECTS%20OF%20ASPECT%20AND%20TELICITY%20ON%20SENTENCE%20COMPREHENSION%20IN%20YOUNG%20ADULTS,-Sunday%2C%20February%2019&text=Lexical%20aspect%20divides%20into%20two,endpoint%20(e.g.%2C%20tickle).) denote an event **with an inherent endpoint** (e.g., ***rescue***); **atelic** verbs denote an event without an inherent endpoint (e.g., ***tickle***).

Comment: ...but that's a pretty broad brush. It's not impossible to say ***Stop rescuing me**!*